# Add a specific key to a contact in android phonebook to easily identify it

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

I have a app which takes all the contacts from phone book and check them in my server to check if they are present or not. For which I normally take all the phone numbers each time and check for the sync.

What I want to know if there is any key which is attached to a contact item and we can change with our value so we dont have to send all numbers to server each time, we will just send those numbers which do not have value set by us. In this way we can differentiate the synced and unsynced numbers?

Comment: I don't think so. You can save the synced numbers in an sqlite database. Before syncing next time compare all contacts with the numbers in database and sync contacts which are not present in the database.

Comment: This will be a pain cause it will take lot of time then.. First on ehas to check contacts---->then own db----->then server. Is not it?

Comment: @JossyPaul...This will take time however I saw Whatsapp is doing this effectively for the next sync after the first one. There is no delay whats so ever. There is another doubt, how do whatsapp know if we add or delete a contact from phonebook?